# Crear Clase para sumar amortiguaciones y descontar a un total PHP

Tags: php, function, class

Buenas noches e creado una funcion la cual recive una cadena de texto y la descompone con un explode capturando los montos y luego los suma para finalmente restar el total de esa suma al monto a pagar:

```
function sumar_multipagos($multipagos=null,$total=0){
    if($multipagos){
        $_pagos = explode(";",$multipagos);
        $resta = 0;
        foreach($_pagos as $pago){
            $_pago = explode(":",$pago);
            $resta = $resta + $_pago[0];
        }
        return $total - $resta;
    }else{
        return $total;
    }
}
```

Desearia volver esta funcion una clase para mejor visualizacion; y me parece que se puede optimizar aun mas el codigo, pienso que en el foreach se puede evitar el `explode` pero no tengo los conocimientos avanzados para lograrlo, agradeceria enormemente su ayuda.

Nota:

- Asi se invoca la funcion:

> echo sumar_multipagos("100:2;50.60:3",500);
> retorna 349.4

en donde el primer parametro esta compuesto por **Monto_a_amortiguar : id_de_medio_de_pago** y el segundo parametro es el total del pedido

Comment: ¿Porqué quieres quitar el explode? Creo que salvo que le pases los valores dentro de un array a tu funcíón lo necesitas.
Como esta puedes quitar el `else`, con dejar en `return` te vale. Como tienes un `return` al final del bloque `if` ese `else` no es necesario.

Comment: *pienso que en el `foreach` se puede evitar el explode pero no tengo los conocimientos avanzados ...* ... Tu intuición es fina en ese punto, piensas eso porque el segundo dato no se usa en tu método (lo que sería `$_pago[1]`). Entonces hay un vacío en alguna parte, una mala práctica o lo que sea, porque **tu método está recibiendo datos que no necesita**. Es evidente que hace falta optimizar, ahora bien, sin conocer el contexto, poco podremos ayudarte en ese sentido. En una clase tú podrías sin demasiados rodeos, crear un objeto que represente la realidad de tus datos en sus propiedades

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Desearia volver esta funcion una clase para mejor visualizacion; y me parece que se puede optimizar aun mas el codigo, pienso que en el foreach se puede evitar el explode pero no tengo los conocimientos avanzados para lograrlo ...*

Tu intuición es fina en ese punto, y es que el método `sumarMultiPagos()` estaría recibiendo una parte que nunca usa y haciendo un trabajo que no le corresponde (el `explode`). Si necesitaras hacer otros trabajos con los datos, necesitarás volver a hacer `explode` ... Generalmente una clase se diseña para tener las cosas ordenadas desde el principio, para eso la clase tiene propiedades o miembros, así que es mejor tener un método que prepare los datos y que ese método se ocupe, **una sola vez** de informar a las propiedades de esa clase con la realidad de los datos y luego usar esas propiedades.

Recuerda que uno de los propósitos de la POO es re-utilizar código. Imaginemos que podrías necesitar también un informe a modo de lista, de los id de pago y los montos, o solamente del total de pagos (sin la diferencia).

Podríamos reflejar todo eso en una clase del siguiente modo:

```
class MultiPago
{
    private $mTotal;
    private $mData;

    public function __construct($data, $total) {
        $this->mTotal=$total;
        $this->prepareData($data);
    }

    private function prepareData($data) {
        $items=explode(";", $data);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $parts=explode(":",$item);
            $this->mData[]=array('monto'=>$parts[0], 'idMedio'=>$parts[1]);           
        }      
    } 
    
    public function showData() 
    {
        echo ("Medio\t Monto \n");
        foreach ($this->mData as $data) {
            printf("%s \t %s \n",$data['idMedio'],$data['monto']);
        }
    }    
    
    public function sumarMultiPagos() 
    {
         $sum = array_sum(array_column($this->mData,'monto'));
         return $sum;
    }
    
    public function getBalance() 
    {
         return $this->mTotal - $this->sumarMultiPagos();
    }    
     
}
```

Si observas, en el constructor se está definiendo la realidad de los datos en propiedades. El método `prepareData()` va a crear un array multidimensional que guardará por separado cada pago, con su monto y su id. Luego usaremos este array, llamando la key que necesitemos de él según el método. Cuando queramos sumar montos, llamaremos a la key `monto` solamente. Cabe decir que este es un diseño aún muy precario, porque `$mData`, en vez de un array asociativo, podría ser un array de objetos del tipo `Pago`, con propiedades llamadas `idPago, monto` y con sus propios métodos, validaciones, etc.

Además, los mismos datos, pasados a lo bruto de este modo al constructor: `"100:2;50.60:3",500` podrían ser mapeados como objetos al momento de obtenerlos, digamos, desde una base de datos o desde una API, o un archivo o cualquier otra fuente ... pero no nos metamos en eso.

Finalmente, la *convención de nombre* es importante. Tu método, según su nombre, debe sumar los pagos. Si quieres una diferencia entre la suma y el total de pagos, el método debería llamarse `getBalance()` o algo parecido. Uno de los grandes propósitos de la POO es que la programación se parezca a la realidad de las cosas. No puedes llamar sumarPagos a un método que no suma pagos solamente, sino que resta del total esos pagos, eso en la realidad se llama balance.

Ahora hagamos una prueba más amplia de la clase, donde le damos varios usos.

[**<kbd>VER DEMO EN REXTESTER</kbd>**](https://rextester.com/JSBW9148)

```
$mp=new MultiPago("100:2;50.60:3",500);    
var_dump($mp);
```

**Salida:**

Aquí tienes tu objeto, con sus propiedades organizadas:

```
object(MultiPago)#1 (2) {
  ["mTotal":"MultiPago":private]=>
  int(500)
  ["mData":"MultiPago":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["monto"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["idMedio"]=>
      string(1) "2"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["monto"]=>
      string(5) "50.60"
      ["idMedio"]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
var_dump($mp->sumarMultipagos());
```

**Salida:**

```
float(150.6)
```

El total de pagos sin más, porque el método, según el nombre, debe sumar los pagos, nada más.

---

```
var_dump($mp->getBalance());
```

**Salida:**

El balance, es decir: total - pagos

```
float(349.4)
```

---

```
$mp->showData();
```

**Salida:**

Una lista de los pagos y el monto, y es que una clase debe servir, por lo general, para varios propósitos. Dado que preparamos los datos al inicio, ahora no hay que ir haciendo `explode` por todos lados:

```
Medio    Monto 
2        100 
3        50.60
```

---

Como dije más arriba, la clase es muy básica. Hay muchas cosas que faltan, como validar que los datos no son nulos, que el `explode` produce un array, etc. La intención es dar una idea de lo que se puede hacer con POO si piensas desde el principio en modelar los datos reflejándolos en propiedades de tu clase que luego podrás reutilizar en diferentes contextos de la clase sin tener que estar preparando los datos constantemente.

Comment: amigo dejame decirte que tu codigo es excelente, no solo respondiste mi pregunta si no le agregaste funciones que me van a ahorrar muchas lineas de codigo y automatizar muchos procesos, gracias me sirvio bastante

Answer (score 2):

No se si te refieres a algo así:

```
class Operaciones
{
    public static function sumarMultipagos(string $multipagos = null, float $total = 0) : float
    {
        $resta = 0;
        if (!is_null($multipagos)) {
            foreach (explode(";", $multipagos) as $pago) {
                $resta += explode(":", $pago)[0];
            }
        }
        return $total - $resta;
    }
}
$multipagos = "100:2;50.60:3";
$total = 500;
echo Operaciones::sumarMultipagos($multipagos, $total); // retorna 349.4
```

Como no dices que más llevará la clase, me he imaginado que serán operaciones de algún tipo, pero puedes renombrarla a lo que te apetezca.

El resto es simplificación de tu código en menos líneas, pero hace lo mismo, no aprecio gran diferencia con lo que tenias, a excepción de quitar el **else** como ya te han dicho en los comentarios.  No se ver cómo quitar algún **explode** de los que haces.

**Actualización**: He modificado ligeramente el nombre de la clase y del método para seguir con los estándares de nombres de PSR1 para [clases (con StudlyCaps)](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#3-namespace-and-class-names) y [métodos (con camelCase)](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/#43-methods)

Comment: me sirve amigo, gracias !!